# How to convert LDAP AuthenticationManagerBuilder to AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I'm using the following LDAP configuration that makes use of `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`:

```
public static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            for (String ldapUrl : ldapUrls) { //I have multiple LDAP servers that must be included
                auth.ldapAuthentication()
                        .userSearchFilter("...")
                        .contextSource()
                        .url(ldapUrl + ldapBase)
                        .managerDn(ldapUsername)
                        .managerPassword(ldapPassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As per the following docs, there is a new way of providing LDAP authentication beans:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#ldap-authentication > LDAP Authentication

```
@Bean
AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager(
        BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
    LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = 
        new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(contextSource);
    factory.setUserDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people");
    factory.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new PersonContextMapper());
    return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Question: how can I now transform my old configuration (that includes multiple LDAP urls) into the new beans?

I mean, where can I get the `BaseLdapPathContextSource` from, and feed it with my ldap login credentials and base urls?

Answer (score 1):

As AuthenticationManager only has a single instance per SecurityFilterChain i would think you have to create a set of AuthenticationProvider instead. and add those to you SecurityFilterChain.

Below code is a mock as i'm not sure if LdapContextSource needs more properties to be set and if you want base UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator or something custom.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, List<LdapAuthenticator> ldapAuthenticators) throws Exception
{
    for(LdapAuthenticator authenticator : ldapAuthenticators)
    {
        LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator = new UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(userDetails);

        http.authenticationProvider(new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator));
    }
}

@Bean
public List<BindAuthenticator> ldapAuthenticator()
{
    List<BindAuthenticator> authenticators = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String ldapUrl : ldapUrls)
    {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl); 
        BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        authenticator.setUserSearch(new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("ou=people", "(uid={0})", ldapContextSource));
        authenticators.add(authenticator);
    }
    
    return authenticators;
}
```